# When the WKWebView frame is resized, the content size broken

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, wkwebview

After doing didFinishNavigation, I try to resize the WKWebView frame, causing the loaded content to resize dramatically. How can this be avoided?

For example, after loading the page, I want to get the information from the WKWebView using evaluatingJavaScript to size the content and set the WKWebView to the appropriate size.

Comment: Have you looked at setting the WKWebView.contentMode? There is a property called sizeThatFits(CGSize) that attempts to size the content to the provided size. You could supply that original frame CGSize to that parameter after didFinishNavigation to force a content mode. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode

Answer (score 0):

The approach your are referring to using javascript to detect the webview content height and set height manually, should work for you.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("webview did enter did finish navigation")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let heightOfContent = result as? CGFloat {

                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Also I think @binaryPilot has a good suggestion.

> There is a property called `sizeThatFits(CGSize)` that attempts to size
> the content to the provided size. You could supply that original frame
> `CGSize` to that parameter after didFinishNavigation to force a content
> mode. See: [here][1]
> [1]: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code set webview height while load

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
            self.webViewHeightConstraint?.constant = height as! CGFloat
        })
    }
```